# problems of substituting localhost by true IP in ionic service.js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to deploy my ionic v1 application， which requires change baseURL from localhost:3000 to myip:3000.

before:(works)

```
angular.module('conFusion.services', ['ngResource'])
        .constant("baseURL","http://localhost:3000/")
        .service('menuFactory', ['$http', '$resource', 'baseURL', function($http, $resource,baseURL) {
```

Before(error):

```
angular.module('conFusion.services', ['ngResource'])
        .constant("baseURL","http://160.39.xxx.xxx:3000/")
        .service('menuFactory', ['$http', '$resource', 'baseURL', function($http, $resource,baseURL) {
```

However, after the change, the post request no longer works, the error I got is

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed:
>
> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> exports.Connector.Connector.connect @ livereload.js:74 (anonymous) @
>
> livereload.js:55 (anonymous) @ livereload.js:1152

any idea on how to change my localhost into my ip so that my Mac can serve as a server for other remote devices to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting src in config.xml in the following line :

```
<content src="http://160.39.xxx.xxx:8100" original-src="index.html"/>
```

Comment: i tried in my own browser localhost:3000 can resolve the database, but http://160.39.XX.XXX:8100/ is: This site can’t be reached.160.39.XX.XX took too long to respond.

Comment: 160.39.XX.XXX:8100 should be replaced with your IP. my ionic CLI asks for IP to use and does that automatically